# Fantasy story about an apprentice raising eggs

Tags: story-identification

I read a portion of this book in the mid 2000s. It was a young adult fantasy story about an apprentice of some sort of magical guild that looked after the eggs of some species of animal (perhaps dragon?). These eggs were the power source that the magicians drew from. I feel like there was a parallel story going on in the real (modern day) world, but have no recollection of that side of the story.

I remember some imagery of a large egg (about 3 metres tall) that was partially underground as the cover art, perhaps with the apprentice and a stereotypical magician in a robe and hat.

At some point, there is some sort of awakening, that the apprentice senses when they wake up, which will help them graduate into being a wizard. I think his egg may have hatched?

I never finished the book, but it has been tickling my mind recently. It would have probably been in the 200-400 page range.

Unfortunately my recollection can be tainted by various other mediums, like His Dark Materials (parallel worlds) and Morrowind (kwama egg farms).

Comment: Too much of a longshot to suggest as a full answer since there's plenty that doesn't fit, but any chance it's Peter F. Hamilton's Void trilogy? It's far-future SF but there's a parallel story in the void which is a fantasy with psychic powers, and the main character Edeard starts as an apprentice in the Eggshaping Guild which uses their psy powers to genetically modify animals for service.

Comment: Vague recollection is may be one of the Discworld books with the wizard being Rincewind?

Comment: @starpilotsix I will take a look, but it doesn't sound familiar, especially all the void stuff.

Comment: @SpikeHolden I am not too familiar with the Discworld books, but this was not a comedic book. I don't think it was that well written, but again it's been quite a long time.

Comment: Is there any chance that it involved the character being linked mentally and emotionally with the dragon? And did the story have a colorful egg?

Comment: @SovereignInquiry there may have been a link, but I don't have any clear recollection of what sort of egg it was. Clearly it was large, but I don't remember any dragons showing up in the story (at least until the point I read up to). The eggs I believe were white in color.